# Systemd Timer not executing shell script

Tags: shell, timer, systemd, manjaro

I've been trying to put together a very simple shell script that starts redshift, if it is not already running.

```
#!/bin/sh
if ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep redshift-gtk; then
    exit 0
else
    /usr/bin/redshift-gtk &
    exit 0
fi
```

I've tried running the script multiple times and I'm sure it works.

I am running Manjaro i3 btw. 
I've then tried creating a service and timer in /usr/lib/systemd/system/:

**/usr/lib/systemd/system/redshift.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs redshift

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/bash /home/velo/reshift.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Yes, the name of the script is reshift.

**/usr/lib/systemd/system/redshift.timer**

```
[Unit]
Description=Runs redshift at given intervals
Requires=redshift.service

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* *:45:00
Persistent=true
Unit=redshift.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The timer has been changed to whatever relevant minute mark was close by to trigger it. After each change in OnCalender, I've done:

```
>systemctl daemon-restart
>systemctl restart redshift.timer
>systemctl status redshift.timer
```

Where I'm told that it is running and enabled. Problem is, nothing is executed whenever the timer hits the mark. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you finally find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `systemctl list-timers --all` to check the status of your timers.

Use `systemctl start redshift.timer` to start your timer.

Also, you should put your custom scripts under `/etc/systemd/system`. The `/usr/lib` location is intended for scripts installed by packages.

See also: [Run script every 30 minutes with systemd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198444/run-script-every-30-min-with-systemd)